# LINQ: No support for passing var as method parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I want to encapsulate the following query into a method that returns a query result (i.e. members).

I then want to take another query that will query off of that returned result.

---

I learned that I cannot use var as a parameter type or result type within the method that I want to create. I really wanted to have this support to make my life simple.

Additional details:
MembersItemsControl.Items property has a private member '_ItemsSourceAsList' that is of type 'Users' which is a class that inherits from an ObservableCollection.

---

Any suggestions?

---

The query code is below:

---

```
var members = (from member in MembersItemsControl.Items
               where
               (
                   // Match either male or female selection
                   (member as UserInformation).sex.Equals("Male") == 
                       SeekingMale.IsChecked.Value &&
                   (member as UserInformation).sex.Equals("Female") == 
                       SeekingFemale.IsChecked.Value
               )
               ||
               (
                    // Provide both male and female if both options are selected
                    SeekingMale.IsChecked.Value == true &&
                    SeekingFemale.IsChecked.Value == true
               )
               select member);
```

Comment: I don't really get it. Is it that you're trying to pass anonymous types as parameters/return types?

Comment: What's the type of `MembersItemsControl.Items`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always pass LINQ collection as `IEnumerable<Member>`.

```
public IEnumarable<Member> Foo()
{
    var members = (from member in MembersItemsControl.Items
                   where
                   (
                       // Match either male or female selection
                       (member as UserInformation).sex.Equals("Male") == 
                           SeekingMale.IsChecked.Value &&
                       (member as UserInformation).sex.Equals("Female") == 
                           SeekingFemale.IsChecked.Value
                   )
                   ||
                   (
                        // Provide both male and female if both options are selected
                        SeekingMale.IsChecked.Value == true &&
                        SeekingFemale.IsChecked.Value == true
                   )
                   select member);

    return members;
}
```

Where `Member` is type of items in `MembersItemsControl.Items`.

Comment: To clarify, he type of members is IEnumerable, so you can pass members to a parameter of type IEnumerable.

Comment: Returning an IEnum**e**rable is pretty useless. You need to use the generic implementation of IEnumerable (IEnumerable<T>) for LINQ to be able to do anything useful with it.

Comment: I moved on from this code a while back and found a better way of doing things that didn't require this question. However, I do like the proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you just want to me able to go `var members = GetQuery();`?

You can just treat the results as an `IEnumerable<Member>`:

```
private IEnumerable<Member> GetMemberQuery()
{
    var members = (from member in MembersItemsControl.Items
                   where
                   (
                       // Match either male or female selection
                       (member as UserInformation).sex.Equals("Male") == 
                           SeekingMale.IsChecked.Value &&
                       (member as UserInformation).sex.Equals("Female") == 
                           SeekingFemale.IsChecked.Value
                   )
                   ||
                   (
                       // Provide both male and female if both options are selected
                       SeekingMale.IsChecked.Value == true &&
                       SeekingFemale.IsChecked.Value == true
                   )
                   select member);

    return members;
}
```

Then you can use that query however you like:

```
var otherQuery = GetMemberQuery().Where(x=> x.Name == "Bob");
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to explicitly type your variable `members`  - [var is just a shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) to allow for implicitly typed local variables. If you do have to pass the variable, or return it outside the local scope, you'll have to use an explicitly typed variable - you can find out the type of your variable by hovering over it with your mouse(or look at it with the debugger) - it will tell you the full type you'll have to use.